# How to mock for unit test NUnit HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream in api controller in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, nunit, streamreader

How to mock a web api controller request in c# using NUnit
Here is my controller

```
public class SearchApiController : ApiController
{     

 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Applications(string authToken)
    {
        string req;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
        {
            req = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }


    }   
}
```

I tried test case like this:

```
            var httpRouteDataMock = new Mock<IHttpRouteData>();
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://this.com");
            var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(new HttpConfiguration(), 
            httpRouteDataMock.Object, httpRequestMessage);
            _controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

It is working fine when i use normal mvc controller and ControllerContext

Answer (score 1):

Avoid coupling to `HttpContext`.

`ApiController` already has a property

```
HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }
```

that provides access to the current request.

Change the design

```
public class SearchApiController : ApiController  

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Applications(string authToken) {
        Stream stream = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        string req;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            req = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //...
    }   
}
```

Now the test in your original example relates more closely

```
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://this.com");
//...set the content of the request as needed
httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent("some data");

var httpRouteDataMock = new Mock<IHttpRouteData>();
var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(new HttpConfiguration(), 
    httpRouteDataMock.Object, httpRequestMessage);
_controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;

//...
```

Comment: I tried this but Stream stream = this.Request.Content.`ReadAsStream()`
HttpResponseMessage  does not contain **ReadAsStream**